# Mongodb multiple indices per field

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

To enable unique index in node I do:

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex({
        'name': 1,
    }, function(err, result) {
        //nothing
    });
});
```

But I would like to enable text index on name also. So after doing the above I do:

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex({
        'name': 'text'
    }, function(err, result) {
        //nothing
    });
});
```

This perfectly creates both indices. My question is, is there any chance to merge this code?? I tried with

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex({
        'name': 1,
        'name': 'text'
    }, function(err, result) {
        //nothing
    });
});
```

but this creates just the text index.

Comment: you want to create two indexes.  that requires running two create index commands.

Answer (score 1):

To enable unique index in node you need to do :

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex(
        {'name': 1},
        {unique:true}, 
        function(err, result) {
        //nothing
    });
});
```

Now to merge this code:(If no-ordering is specified for index then it is ascending order)

```
City.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.ensureIndex(
        {'name': 'text'},
        {unique:true},
        function(err, result) {
        //nothing
    });
});
```

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `.ensureIndex({name:'text'},{unique:true},function(err, result){ ... nothing ...})` ?

Comment: yes @lascort... edited the post, I had missed the braces , thanks.